# How can I add a break line after the header of a sequence and before the actual sequence?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I have a file with multiple sequences, the problem is that after the id there is a space and then the actual sequence, I want to add a break line between the id and the actual sequence.

This is what I have:

```
UniRef90_Q8YC41 Putative binding protein BMEII0691 MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA
```

This is what I want it to look like:

```
UniRef90_Q8YC41 Putative binding protein BMEII0691
MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA
```

If its possible I would rather it look like this

```
UniRef90_Q8YC41
MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Using `awk`, printing first and last field with `\n` as delimiter:

  ```
  awk '{printf "%s\n%s\n", $1, $NF}' file.txt
  ```
- Using `sed`, capturing first and last field while matching and using in replacement:

  ```
  sed -E 's/([^[:blank:]]+).*[[:blank:]]([^[:blank:]]+)$/\1\n\2/' file.txt
  ```
- With `perl`, similar logic to `sed`:

  ```
  perl -pe 's/^([^\s]+).*\s([^\s]+)/$1\n$2/' file.txt
  ```
- Using `bash`, *slower approach*, creating an array from each line and printing first and last element from the array separating them by `\n`:

  ```sh
  while read -ra line; do printf '%s\n%s\n' "${line[0]}" \
         "${line[$((${#line[@]]}-1))]}"; done <file.txt
  ```
- With `python`, creating a list containing whitespace separated elements from each line, then printing the first and last element from the list, separating by `\n`:

  ```py
  #!/usr/bin/env python3
  with open("file.txt") as f:
      for line in f:
          line = line.split()
          print(line[0]+'\n'+line[-1])
  ```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt                               
UniRef90_Q8YC41 Putative binding protein BMEII0691 MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA
UniRef90_Q8YC41 Putative binding protein BMEII0691 MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA

$ awk '{printf "%s\n%s\n", $1, $NF}' file.txt                             
UniRef90_Q8YC41
MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA
UniRef90_Q8YC41
MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA

$ sed -E 's/([^[:blank:]]+).*[[:blank:]]([^[:blank:]]+)$/\1\n\2/' file.txt
UniRef90_Q8YC41
MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA
UniRef90_Q8YC41
MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA

$ perl -pe 's/^([^\s]+).*\s([^\s]+)/$1\n$2/' file.txt
UniRef90_Q8YC41
MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA
UniRef90_Q8YC41
MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA


$ while read -ra line; do printf '%s\n%s\n' "${line[0]}" "${line[$((${#line[@]]}-1))]}"; done <file.txt
UniRef90_Q8YC41
MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA
UniRef90_Q8YC41
MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA

>>> with open("file.txt") as f:
...     for line in f:
...         line = line.split()
...         print(line[0]+'\n'+line[-1])
... 
UniRef90_Q8YC41
MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA
UniRef90_Q8YC41
MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA
```

Comment: Alternative perl: `perl -ne '@a=split(/ +/); print("$a[0]\n$a[$#a]")'`

Comment: ... or simply `perl -alne 'print "$F[0]\n$F[-1]"'`

Comment: Thank you very much @heemayl, now I will get my manual on awk and sed to understand the commands, I will leave the perl and the others for a later ocasion.

Comment: @asp2_downhill Glad I could help :)

Comment: Regarding python2: you do **not** have to change syntax, that syntax will work fine and produce the same result in both python2 and python3. In python3 `print(expr)` is parsed as a function call with a single argument `expr` in python2 `print(expr)` is parsed as the `print` statement whose unique argument is `(expr)` which is the same as `expr`. There would be a difference only if you put commas inside `expr` or you use keyword arguments.

Comment: @Bakuriu I didn't know that.. Edited.. thanks

Answer (score 6):

In this answer:

1. `bash` + `xargs` one-liner
2. `python` one-liner
3. `Ruby` one-liner

#### 1. `bash` + `xargs` version.

```
$> cat input_file.txt  | xargs -L 1 bash -c 'for i; do : ; done ; echo $1;echo $i' bash
```

This essentially gives each line to bash as command line arguments, loop till we get the last one , and echo them out.

Demo:

```
$> cat input_file.txt                                                                     
UniRef90_Q8YC41 Putative binding protein BMEII0691 MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA
UniRef90_Q8YC41 Putative binding protein BMEII0691 MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA
$> cat input_file.txt  | xargs -L 1 bash -c 'for i; do : ; done ; echo $1;echo $i' bash   
UniRef90_Q8YC41
MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA
UniRef90_Q8YC41
MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA
```

Even shorter version:

```
$> cat input_file.txt  | xargs -L 1 bash -c 'echo $1;echo ${@: -1}' bash                  
UniRef90_Q8YC41
MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA
UniRef90_Q8YC41
MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA
```

---

#### 2 .`python` one-liner

This  one-liner assembles a list of strings that are basically first word + newline + last word. Finally, it prints all list items as one string joined with newline.

```
python -c 'import sys ; print "\n".join([ l.split()[0] + "\n" + l.split()[-1]  for l in sys.stdin ])' < input_file.txt
```

Usage demo:

```
$ python -c 'import sys ; print "\n".join([ l.split()[0] + "\n" + l.split()[-1]  for l in sys.stdin ])' < input_file.txt
UniRef90_Q8YC41
MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA
UniRef90_Q8YC41
MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA
```

---

#### 3. Ruby one liner

In this one liner, `-n` flag works as `while gets . . . end` loop. `$_` holds value of each line read, so  per each line we split it into an array of words, and then print first and last one.

```
$ ruby -ne 'words=$_.split(); puts words[0],words[-1]' < input_file.txt                   
UniRef90_Q8YC41
MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA
UniRef90_Q8YC41
MNRFIAFFRSVFLIGLVATAFGRACA
```

Comment: Thank you @serg, I will take a course on python later on to learn how to use it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

#### Ruby Version

```ruby
File.open(ARGV[0]) do |f|
  f.each do |line|
    puts "#{line.partition(' ')[0] + "\n" + line.rpartition(' ')[-1]}"
  end
end
```

Save it as any name say `line_breaker.rb` and run it with `ruby line_breaker.rb file.txt` while *file.txt* is the file where you have the sequences stored.